# Send Excel file to printer in batch job

Tags: excel, batch-file, axapta, jobs, dynamics-ax-2012

I will print excel file in a AX 2012 batchjob.

I chose this approach because the template is too complex to draw it in SSRS. 
So, I already have a class which works with excel COM object without any problems on client. Then I created a similar class which runs on server. I used WinAPIServer instead of WinAPI, COM interopt, etc.

But now I've an error:

> "workBooks" method is not supported by Automation Interface of COM-object "Excel.Application"

Note - AOS is installed on another machine.

Why is it happening? 
Are there some special things in working with COM on AX-server side ?

I already tried to change properties of "Microsoft excel application" in different ways.

Comment: Could you make a sample class to reproduce the error?

Comment: Try running it on a client on the AOS server, does it work then? Should excel be installed on the aos server for your code to work? Also what Jan says :) .